# Force python to use ' instead of " for strings

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a script that migrates data from one database to another written in python and sql using the psycopg2 library.

I retrieve a string from the first database and store it for later in a list so I can put it into the second database when I finish gathering all the data I need.

If the string has an apostrophe in it then python will represent the string using " ". The problem with this is that sql interprets " " as specifying a column name and ' ' for strings whereas python interprets both as strings. I wish to force python to use apostrophes to represent the string (or another suitable workaround)

Google has not turned up anything. Can't even find a mention of the fact that python will use " " when you have apostrophes in your string. I have considered replacing apostrophes in my string with a different character and converting it back later but this seems like a clumsy solution.

For example

```py
MyString = 'it\'s'
MyList = [MyString]
print(MyList) # returns "it's"
print(MyList[0]) # returns it's
```

When I insert the new values into the database I am in inserting the whole list as the values.

```sql
INSERT INTO table VALUES MyList
```

This is where the error crops up because the string is using " " instead of ' '.
A solution on either the python or sql side would work.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Not just because of this issue, but for many other reasons, you should use [parametrised SQL statements](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), which make this issue moot. From psycopg2 docs: "**Warning:** Never, **never, NEVER** use Python string concatenation (`+`) or string parameters interpolation (`%`) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint." (psycopg2 docs are a bit old, or they would also include f-strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix. It's a bit janky but it works. Convert the list into a string. Use the replace function like so:

```py
    MyString = MyString.replace('"',"'")
```

And then use that string instead.

Comment: I had the opposite requirement, from ' to " basically to create a valid JSON string. I think there should be an option in the string API to pass which quotation to be used.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to convert to a string. That will always give you " because the ' is not actually valid json.

```py
import json

MyList = ['hi', 'there']
MyString = json.dumps(MyList)
print(MyString)  # ["hi", "there"]
```